# Invoking an event from a JavaScript class using this cause a SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, html, oop

What I want to do is to create a custom dynamic input. So I wrapped my custom input in a class, an img tag serves like a button, so I handled click in an attribute, which invokes a class method using this, but this logic generates a syntax error.

Here is the code of the class I created:

```
class Description {
    constructor(value) {
        this._value = value;
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(text) {
        this._value = text;
    }

    test() {
        console.log("Dummy Text");
    }

    build() {
        return `<div class="row" >
            <img src="./icons/add.png" class="icon" onclick="${this.test}" /> 
            Intitulé : <input type="text" size="50" value="${this.value}"/>
        </div>`;
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: '{'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlers can only be inlined like that if they're standalone global variables, which `test` is not. Create a `<div>`, insert the HTML, and attach the event listener to the child and return the `<div>`.

```
class Description {
    constructor(value) {
        this._value = value;
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(text) {
        this._value = text;
    }

    test() {
        console.log("Dummy Text");
    }

    build() {
        const row = document.createElement('div');
        row.className = 'row';
        row.innerHTML = `
            <img src="./icons/add.png" class="icon" /> 
            Intitulé : <input type="text" size="50" value="${this.value}"/>
        `;
        row.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', () => this.test());
        return row;
    }
}
```

But this can allow arbitrary code execution due to the string interpolation into the HTML markup. Better to assign to the `.value` of the input instead.

```
class Description {
    constructor(value) {
        this._value = value;
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(text) {
        this._value = text;
    }

    test() {
        console.log("Dummy Text");
    }

    build() {
        const row = document.createElement('div');
        row.className = 'row';
        row.innerHTML = `
            <img src="./icons/add.png" class="icon" /> 
            Intitulé : <input type="text" size="50">
        `;
        row.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', () => this.test());
        row.querySelector('input').value = this.value;
        return row;
    }
}
```